# Substitute the variables in the Isabelle/HOL Isar proof

Tags: isabelle

I'm writing an Isar proof inside the *Isabelle2020* and working with the *locales*.
On some point I want to use the *axiom* from the *locale*, which states

```
((A.par x y) ∧ (F x ≃ F y)) → (x ≃ y)
```

where "A" is another *locale* given as the information for the one where the above axiom is stored, "A.par" is simply a predicate then.
All the predicates and functions in the Axiom use polymorphic types, the free variable "x" itself is of type *'a*, for example, the function "F" is of type *'a => 'b* and "G" is of type *'b => 'c*:

```
F :: "'a => 'b" 
G :: "'b => 'c"
x :: "'a"
```

Generally, I have to axioms of this form: one for the locale "F" (showed above) and one for the locale "G" (which is exactly the same but with other types here):

```
((A.par x y) ∧ (G x ≃ G y)) → (x ≃ y)
```

The problem is that inside the proof I want to use this axiom but applied as

```
(A.par (F x) (F y)) ∧ (G(F x) ≃ G(F y)) → (F x) ≃ (F y)
```

Here the types coincide (as I see), because "F x" is of type *'b* and "G" is applied exactly on this type.
And it seems I have to explicitly show the prover that "(F x)" here should be considered as "x" in the axiom and so on.
The proof step itself is just to apply the lemma to the conclusion I have already got:

```
(A.par (F x) (F y)) ∧ (G(F x) ≃ G(F y))
```

to get

```
(F x) ≃ (F y)
```

If we take a look on the output of the Isabelle we will see these:
USING 1)

```
((E (domain' (F x)) ∧ ¬ (¬ (E (domain' (F y))) ∨ domain' (F x) ≠ domain'
(F y))) ∧ E (codomain' (F x)) ∧ ¬ (¬ (E (codomain' (F y))) ∨ codomain' 
(F x) ≠ codomain' (F y))) ∧ E (G (F x)) ∧ ¬ (¬ (E (G (F y))) ∨ G (F x) ≠ G
(F y))
```

AND 2)

```
(E ?x ∧ ¬ (¬ (E ?y) ∨ ?x ≠ ?y)) ← (((E (domain' ?x) ∧ ¬ (¬ (E (domain' ?y
)) ∨ domain' ?x ≠ domain' ?y)) ∧ E (codomain' ?x) ∧ ¬ (¬ (E (codomain' ?y
)) ∨ codomain' ?x ≠ codomain' ?y)) ∧ E (G ?x) ∧ ¬ (¬ (E (G ?y)) ∨ G ?x ≠ G 
?y))
```

GET THIS

```
E (F x) ∧ ¬ (¬ (E (F y)) ∨ F x ≠ F y)
```

So, here one should merely use the 2)nd fact with substituted schematic variables by "F x" and "F y".
Will be glad to see any suggestions.

Comment: Can you post a complete example? In particular: what is the type of F? It's important that F returns the same type as the type of x in the axiom you want to use.

Comment: @PeterZeller, I have just added the information regarding the types of predicates, functions and variables used in the question. Hope, I made the question clearer.

Comment: I am still not quite sure how your locales are set up, but I guess that the polymorphism of `F` and `G` is the cause for non matching types. If you have the assumption `A.par (F x) (F y)` then Isabelle would infer some type `'x` for `F x` in the assumption and another type `'y` for the `F x` in the conclusion. If you want them to be the same type you need to add explicit type annotations.

Comment: @PeterZeller, If it helps, I might upload the definition of the locale, F and G are just the examples (instantiations) of that locale. But better, I will upload the output shown by Isabelle to see the problem directly (it will unfold the definitions of all the predicates and so on, so might look clumsy). As I understand, with types there everything should be okay. The problem is to use "F x" and "F y" in the schematic variables of the axiom "?x" and "?y".

Comment: If `2` is the name of the fact you want to instantiate, you can write something like `2[where x=‹F x› and y=‹F y›]` to instantiate the variables. However, in most cases it is not necessary to instantiate variables manually. If you bring your axioms in a normalized form with meta implication (`⟹` instead of `∧` and `⟶`) you can usually use simple rule application which automatically instantiates the schematic variables correctly. The `rule_format` attribute might be useful for this. If you upload a small theory showing your problem it would be easier to give more concrete advice.

Comment: @A.Gonus I believe that this question would greatly benefit from a minimal reproducible example (also, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Generally, it is acceptable and conventional to post reasonably large code fragments on Stack Overflow.